# jquery lightbox in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, lightbox

I'm having a hard time trying to make jquery lightbox in codeigniter work. What I want to happen is to pop a youtube thumbnail and play the video on the lightbox. I stored it outside my 
application directory, I included it in my config file like this:

`$config['jquery'] = "js/jquery1.4.2.js";`

then I include on the view file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo "$base"."js/jquery1.4.2.js"; ?>"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo "$base"."js/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"; ?>"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo "$base"."js/css/jquery-lightbox-0.5.css"; ?>" media="screen" />
```

The controller function is like this:

```
$data['css'] = $this->config->item('css');
$data['jquery'] = $this->config->item('jquery');
$this->load->view('aboutus',$data);
```

and it doesn't work.

...I tried the plugin on a static test html page, it works fine :(

Comment: Looks like `$data['css/jquery']` are never used? Also, whats `$base`? The same as `base_url()` or something else?

Comment: <code>$config['base_url']= "http://ci/myapp/";</code>

Comment: `$config['base_url']` != the `$base` you are using. Try DRL's answers from below.

Comment: I assigned it like this
$data['base'] = $this->config->item('base_url').. I just didn't posted it above

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would include the files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jquery1.4.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/css/jquery-lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
```

Assuming js/ is in the root of your public_html.  If its not you will need the full relative path like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/file.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: here's the url of test site http://digitustest.zzl.org/home/aboutus please advise me what to do..when i click the youtube thumbnail..it goes to youtube website and not in a lightbox :(

Comment: Hi sasori, your base_url appears to be wrong; in application/config/config.php you need to put $config['base_url'] = "http://digitustest.zzl.org/home/";  And then include the files as per my answer above.

Comment: thanks for the comment..but if I'll add /home/ to the base_url, it'll remove the main css file
the current config file of that live test site is this

    $config['base_url'] = "http://digitustest.zzl.org/";
    $config['css'] = "css/styles.css";

Comment: Your lightbox files are showing up as not found so there is something wrong with the path; is the js/ folder in the same directory as the css/ folder?  If not, put it there.

Comment: outside the application directory , I have css, js, images directories,,I extracted the lightbox package inside that js directory..thats why I have a js/js/jquery , and js/css/jquery-lightbox css sort of stuff ....and it didn't help even if I moved all the lightbox stuff from the main js directory to the main css directory including the lightbox js stuff